# from_db_value() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have simple django notification table with the following structure

```
+-------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| level                         | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| unread                        | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| actor_object_id               | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| verb                          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description                   | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| target_object_id              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| action_object_object_id       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timestamp                     | datetime(6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| public                        | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| action_object_content_type_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| actor_content_type_id         | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| recipient_id                  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| target_content_type_id        | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| deleted                       | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| emailed                       | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| data                          | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

And all what i want is to fetch the content so this is my view

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@login_required()
def getnotifications(request, page):

    try:
        if page == None:
            page = 1

        userID = request.user
        unreadnum = Notification.objects.filter(recipient=request.user,
                                                unread=True).count()
        notifs = Notification.objects.filter(recipient=userID, unread=True).distinct().order_by(
            '-timestamp')
        print("got ntifs")
        paginator = Paginator(notifs, 10)
        paginatednotifs = paginator.page(page)
        return Response(
            {"notifications": NotificationSerializer(paginatednotifs,many=True, context={"user": request.user}).data,
             "unread": unreadnum,"has_next":paginatednotifs.has_next()})


    except Exception as e:
        print("========")
        print(str(e))
        return Response(
            {"notifications": str(e)})
```

and thus view's serilizer is like this :

```
class NotificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    actor = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    target = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Notification
        fields = ("id","actor", "target","timestamp","verb")

    def get_actor(self,obj):
        user = Useraccount.objects.get(user__id=obj.actor_object_id)
        return UserAccountSerializer(user,many=False,context={"user":self.context["user"]}).data

    def get_target(self,obj):

        if obj.target_content_type.model == "action":

            action = ActstreamAction.objects.get(id=obj.target_object_id)
            return ActionNotificationSerializer(action,many=False).data
        return {"targetType":obj.target_content_type.model,"action":obj.action_object_content_type.model}
```

i tried to make many modifications in the serilizer and the view but always and always the same error

```
from_db_value() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

i couldn't find this `from_db_value()`  function
i'm really having a hard time with this problem, and i know just the basics about Django

i'm using

- django : 1.11.18
- djangorestframework : 3.6.4
- mysql : 5.7.25

A traceback for the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<homedir>/project/webServer/app/myNotifications/views.py", line 66, in getnotifications
    {"notifications": NotificationSerializer(paginatednotifs,many=True, context={"user": request.user}).data,
  File "<homedir>/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 739, in data
    ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
  File "<homedir>/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 263, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "<homedir>/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 657, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "<homedir>/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 657, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_collections_abc.py", line 883, in __iter__
    v = self[i]
  File "<homedir>/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 145, in __getitem__
    self.object_list = list(self.object_list)
  File "<homedir>/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "<homedir>/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1121, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "<homedir>/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 62, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "<homedir>/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 847, in results_iter
    row = self.apply_converters(row, converters)
  File "<homedir>/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 832, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, self.connection, self.query.context)
TypeError: from_db_value() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Comment: What version of Django and Django Rest Framework do you use? What database?

Comment: Thank you, i've updated my post

Comment: Are you using any non-standard fields? JSONField, or ArrayField or GeometryField or any other fields that deals with data structures that are more
complex than strings, dates, integers, or floats? I guess that there is a mismatch in versions of different libraries

Comment: It might useful if you get the whole traceback for the error. You can get the traceback using `print(traceback.format_exc())` in your catched exception. Import it with `import traceback`

Comment: Thank you for your comment @MichałS. i've edited my post and added the traceback, and about the non standard fields i'm using the default notification table, i think it has a JSONField

Comment: Ok, one more question: what version of `django-notification` do you use? I think it doesn't support Django older 2.2 (and yours is 1.11.18)

Comment: i'm using django-notifications-hq==1.3.0,i think it is compatible with this django version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

Most likely, `jsonfield` package is not incompatible with `Django==1.11.18`

---

**Details**:

You are using Django in version 1.11.18, which requires 5 positional arguments for `from_db_value` method and do not support JSONFields.

You are also using `django-notifications` package, which internally uses `jsonfield>=1.0.3` package. Since there is no max. version set, `django-notifications` uses the newest version of `jsonfield` package.

The newest versions of `jsonfield` (3.0.0 and higher) doesn't support Django below 2.2. One of the reasons is that it takes only 4 arguments instead of 5.

The highest version of `jsonfield` that supports Django 1.11 is `jsonfield==2.1.1`

Please check the version of installed `jsonfield` package (use `grep` only if you're on unix sytem):

```
pip freeze | grep jsonfield
```

If it's 3.0.0 or more, you may try to downgrade it to 2.1.1. Be aware that it may (or may not) cause other compatibility issues with other packages.

Comment: Ah exactly it was the `jsonfield` version, i've downgrade it from `3.1.0` to `3.0.0` and it works like a charm, you've made my week Michal thank you

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error:

```py
  File "/home/django/lee3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 833, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, self.connection, self.query.context)
TypeError: from_db_value() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

The `'from_db_value'` it was complaining about was in `/picklefield/fields.py`.

Changed line 184:
`def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):`
to:
`def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context=None):`
Everything works fine now.